# Pass pagination arguments in Fauna Function

Tags: reactjs, faunadb, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to build fauna function which will accept `before` or `after` arguments in `Paginate` function, but when I run it I have error `Array, Set, or Page expected, String provided`
So this arguments are only provided as string.

This is my fauna function:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["paginationAfter", "paginationBefore"],
    If(
      IsEmpty(Var("paginationAfter")),
      If(
        IsEmpty(Var("paginationBefore")),
        Map(
          Paginate(Match(Index("get_logs_by_date")), { size: 10 }),
          Lambda(["created", "ref"], Get(Var("ref")))
        ),
        Map(
          Paginate(Match(Index("get_logs_by_date")), {
            before: Var("paginationBefore"),
            size: 10
          }),
          Lambda(["created", "ref"], Get(Var("ref")))
        )
      ),
      Map(
        Paginate(Match(Index("get_logs_by_date")), {
          after: Var("paginationAfter"),
          size: 10
        }),
        Lambda(["created", "ref"], Get(Var("ref")))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Any help is appreaciated.
Note that I'm not using GRAPHQL
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `IsEmpty`, which requires an array or set. Instead, try using `IsNull` instead.